# How to open “Performance Options” dialog from command line or system call in XP

Tags: command-line, windows-xp

Is there a way to automatically open up the Windows "Performance Options advanced" dialog using the command line or a system call in windows XP?

The long way to get there is to go to Start, right-click on "Computer", then select "Advanced System Settings"-> Settings-> Advanced Tab.

In windows 7, i can do with command:
SystemPropertiesPerformance /pagefile

But in Windows XP:
i can reach only to advanced tab using following command: 
control Sysdm.cpl,,3

I need to open Virtual memory settings page from command line in windows XP?

Answer (score 0):

I have spent 5 hours looking for you and what I found is this:
Search engines ask, yahoo, google, dogpile, etc reveal nothing.
I read a great deal of the technet library on 2000 and xp and found nothing.
I also tried explore /n::{clsid} trying various configurations to no avail.
I also tried shell:command with various syntax with no benefits.
I did find a command line tool that will show the memory and edit it.

wmic memphysical list full
and then there was pagefileconfig.vbs on microsoft.com